# Maven release plugin throwing Hostname Not found exception?

Tags: maven-release-plugin

I am trying to release a project in jenkins and getting a host not found exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.PerforceScmProvider.generateDefaultClientspecName(PerforceScmProvider.java:420)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.PerforceScmProvider.getClientspecName(PerforceScmProvider.java:395)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.perforce.command.checkout.PerforceCheckOutCommand.executeCheckOutCommand(PerforceCheckOutCommand.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.checkout.AbstractCheckOutCommand.executeCommand(AbstractCheckOutCommand.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:59)
```

Reading through the source it looks like the exception is thrown on this line:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

Since I don't control the source for the release plugin other than changeing the code is there some way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the work around. on command line run the command

```
hostname <your-ip or actual-hostname>
```